# How can I allow users to only create ec2 instances in a permitted subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc, subnet

I want to allow users to only run/stop ec2 instances in permitted subnets, but the code as follows didn't work:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:TerminateInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:RunScheduledInstances",
        "ec2:UnmonitorInstances"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:ArnEquals": {
            "ec2:Subnet": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/subnet-*******",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/subnet-*******",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/subnet-*******"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, share which kind of error the code returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This policy will allow users to only run EC2 instances in a specific subnet both programmatically and through the console:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                    "ec2:RunInstances",
                    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                    "ec2:StopInstances",
                    "ec2:StartInstances",
                    "ec2:RunScheduledInstances",
                    "ec2:UnmonitorInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/subnet-******",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Adapted from this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2_instances-subnet.html)